# PHP include textfiles and print in correct area

Tags: php, html, css

Right, so in order to test myself and the works of a dynamic webpage; I have saved footer, header, navigation etc in textfiles. I use a php script to read these files and display the page, that's all fine and dandy.

However the problem starts to occur when I have a separate textfile with some text, that I would like to print out in the `<section><article></article></section>`
If I print it directly into the section.txt it works fine, but I would like to have a separate file in order to make it more dynamic, called bunchoftext.txt when I use the code down below it does not print in the section area. How could I make it do this? Also please note I'm using a textfile for learning purposes. Might switch to database later on, but I would like to get this sorted first.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("bunchoftext.txt", "r");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    echo $buffer;
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: OK, is the `<?php` block in the `<section>`?

Comment: <section></section> is in a textfile called section.txt, I use the above code to retrieve the information from it, hence writing out the <html> in the include.php - therefore, no I can't use php in the textfile, right?

Comment: You can if you change it to a php file... But am I to understand that you have two text files, section.tyxt and bunchoftext.txt, and the contents of the latter are to be inserted in the contents of the first, which is then inserted in the output file? That sounds a bit convoluted.

Comment: I use a included.php script that opens up header.txt, footer.txt, nav.text etc etc. This creates the page. I then have a bunch of products stored in different texfiles, article1.txt, article2.txt etc. However, I don't know how to implement these in the <section></section> area of the webpage without putting them in the section.txt Any ideas? Would appreciate it immensely

Answer (score 0):

You can create one folder where your index.php or your main php file is and place all `article.txt` files in and use next code to get their content and place it `section` element for each one

```
<?php foreach (glob("articles/*.txt") as $file) { ?>
  <section>
      <?php  $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
      while (!feof($file_handle)) {
          $line = fgets($file_handle);
          echo $line;
      }
      fclose($file_handle); ?>
  </section>
<?php  } ?>
```